# How to share a page without having Facebook share button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-sharer

Let's say, I've my own website with this page, http://sample.com/mypage

I want to share this, http://sample.com/mypage to my Facebook wall. The common way of sharing stuffs back to Facebook wall is by using share button just like how it's placed in Youtube.com etc. Once we click on the share button, it will pop up the share dialog, for us to confirm sharing.

However, what if I want to share it on behalf of user, without having user to press the share button and also the share confirmation dialog ?

Is there something like, the user first grant the permission to the website to share on behalf of them ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you need user account verification and it is illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check into the feed dialog.

> The Feed Dialog prompts the user to publish an individual story to a
>   profile's feed. This does not require any extended permissions.
>
> Your application can also publish directly to a profile's feed without
>   user interaction, use the corresponding Graph API call.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#graphapicall